# Retrieve velocity data from twist messages

Tags: ros, c++, node, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I would like to inspect and pass on the individual velocities from Twist messages, are there methods to do this? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70930/retrieve-velocity-data-from-twist-messages/) by [boog](https://answers.ros.org/users/5329/boog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
you probably want to do something like this (this is an example that converts geometry_msgs/Twist message to turtlesim/Velocity message):

```
def TwistToTurtle(): #initialization
rospy.init_node('TwistToTurtle',anonymous=False)
rospy.Subscriber('cmd_vel',Twist,gotTwistCB) #subscribe to cmd_vel topic which publishes Twist messages 
pub = rospy.Publisher('turtle1/command_velocity',Velocity)
rospy.spin()

def gotTwistCB(data): #when Twist msg is received
#take values from data and do your job, for example:
outdata = Velocity()
outdata.linear = data.linear.x
outdata.angular = data.angular.z
pub.publish(outdata)
```

SO `data.linear.x/y/z` and `data.angular.x/y/z` are the ones that you care about

more on subsribing [tutorial here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29).
Also, you may want to check out [rosmsg](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosmsg) or just run

```
rosmsg -h
```

---

Originally posted by [vonovak](https://answers.ros.org/users/4872/vonovak/) with karma: 88 on 2013-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-08-14**:
Hey @vonovak one quick question - Are the velocity commands in m/s and angular velocity in rads/sec? or is there any other scaling?